# Java - How to keep track of "javaws" process when started programmatically?

Tags: java, process, exec, java-web-start

I know how to start "javaws" (Java Web Start) from a Java program, but I have problems tracking the process instance after created.

The JNLP file used as parameter contains the definition of a program that will start an internal websocket server. The main java program (the one that invokes javaws) has a timer task checking every second if that server has started, to send some instructions to that server.

But sometimes the java web start process ends because of a network error, and the program never loads. The process instance created from the main program seems to lose control of the started javaws program "RIGHT AFTER" created, even if I use .waitFor(); It is like if javaws was started from my java program, then javaws creates another process to continue loading the java program (jnlp), and then it kills the original javaws process. At this point I cannot know from the original java program if the JNLP loading program failed, or if it is taking too long.

Here is the sample code:

```
package some.internalpackage;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OtherProgramStarter {

    protected static Process process = null;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Try every second to connect to the internal websocket server..
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        int begin = 1000;
        int timeinterval = 1000;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            // Maximum 5 minutes
            private int maximumTimes = 300;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // On time-out, display error.
                if (--maximumTimes < 1) {

                    // Show error message
                    String message = "The expected program was not started or could not be detected after 5 minutes. Please try again later.";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "The Program", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.err.println(message);
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                try {

                    // Check if the process is still there
                    if (!process.isAlive()) {

                        // THIS IS ALWAYS PRINTING IN CONSOLE (every second). process is never alive!!?
                        System.out.println("Command internal process is not alive anymore.");
                    }

                    // Try to connect to an existing local server
                    throw new Exception("This is a test exception, the one expected when the internal server is not started (yet).");

                    // If the connection is successful, send some instructions and the close the current program.
                    System.exit(0);

                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    String message = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString() + ": Internal connection failed...";
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            }
        }, begin, timeinterval);

        String jnlpFileUrl = "https://some.existingfile.com/launcher.jnlp";
        try {
            String message = "JNLP URL: " + jnlpFileUrl;
            System.out.println(message);

            // String command = "javaws " + jnlpFileUrl;
            //String fullCommand = "start \"" + PROGRAM_TITLE + "\" /W " + command;
            String fullCommand = "\"" + detectJavaFullPath() + "\" " + jnlpFileUrl;
            message = "Full command: " + fullCommand;
            System.out.println(message);

            // I Have tested with all of these:
            //process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", fullCommand).start();
            //process = new ProcessBuilder(fullCommand).start();
            //process = new ProcessBuilder(detectJavaFullPath(), jnlpFileUrl, "-wait").start();
            //process.waitFor();

            String[] cmd = {detectJavaFullPath(), jnlpFileUrl};
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        } catch (Exception err) {

            String message = "It was not possible to start the other program.";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "The program", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.err.println(message);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static String detectCurrentJarDirFullPath() {
        try {
            File jar = new File(OtherProgramStarter.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
            return jar.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static String detectJavaFullPath() {
        String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
        File f = new File(javaHome);
        f = new File(f, "bin");
        f = new File(f, "javaws.exe");
        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    }

}
```

Please note this is an example based on the real code.

I start first the Timer task, waiting for the process to exist. Then I start the process and keep it's reference in a static class property. Now I can access it from the timer task to check it's alive status, but it always says it is not alive, even after the javaws process is loading the jnlp and it's libraries (I can see it in its own console, plus additional UI feedback generated from the JNLP loading program).

Any suggestions?

All I want is, if the jnlp is loading, to know the process is alive. If the JNLP loading process fails and stops running, to know about that from the main program to display the appropriate error message. I already know if the JNLP program starts correctly due to the successful connection I create from the timer task (a websocket connection).

Thanks.

---

**Update**

I tried running the javaws command by hand on a console while checking the generated processes with "Process Explorer". I see the first process generated is "javaws", but after that a new one is created for "jp2launcher.exe", and then the old process for "javaws" dies. The JNLP program continues to load though, so I think this is probably the reason why I cannot control/know the real state of the loading JNLP process.

Comment: Don't do this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`. Run the JLNP file programatically within the same JVM.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I have tested with `ProcessBuilder` class, but I'm not sure what else can I use.